Message sent to server by client is not null but the sender id and receiver id are null in JavaScript Web Sockets
I am trying to send a message from one client to another client using JavaScript Web Sockets. I get a list of all clients connected to the server via the Web Sockets they used to connect to the server. Then there is a button that when clicked on the client side shows the list of all Web Socket Ids with an active connection to the server. Then when a web socket is clicked, I make sure that Web Socket ID is not the same as the client where the click was triggered with the following code
 let socketid = row.textContent.substring(1, row.textContent.length);
 //make sure the socket id is not the same as current client
 if (socketid == mysockid) {
     alert("You cannot send a challenge to yourself");
 } else {
     //it means the socket id is different and it is a different user
     //create a room with the two socket ids and
     //send a mesage to the target socket id
     let message = "Player A is challenging you to a checkers game";
     //send a message with the socket and not with the socket id
     socket.emit('directMessage', { sender: mysockid, receiver: socketid, message });
     //the message is first sent to the server which re directs the traffic to the target
     console.log(mysockid + " is sending a message to " + socketid);
 }

The message Player A is challenging you to a checkers game is printed on the server terminal which listens on messages sent from client Web Sockets with the following code
    //handle direct communication between sockets connected to the server
    socket.on('directMessage', ({ fromSockId, toSockId, message }) => {
        //check for nulls before re directing the traffic
        console.log("sender: " + fromSockId);
        console.log("receiver: " + toSockId);
        io.to(toSockId).emit('message', { sender: fromSockId, message });
        console.log(message);
        console.log("message relayed to the other client successfully");
    });
});

Except that the socket Ids of the sender and the receiver are null on the terminal as the message undefined  is printed on the server terminal when I log their values inside the method above, how can I make sure the values are not null so the message reaches the target client web socket successfully?

